# using oAuth2 auth dance vs oAuth1 signing

Tags: oauth

I have been reading about *oauth* and *'how to create apis'*.

In oauth2, there is what they call the authentication dance where the client will be requesting a **request token** using a **consumer key** and **consumer secret**. This request token will be used to acquire an access token. The expiring access tokens will be used for requests.

While in the "Step 3" of this [article](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-an-api-centric-web-application--net-23417), they simply sign the data, send the encrypted data and the public key, and check it in the server side. similar to what oAuth1 does. Wherein they create a signature for each request

I am wondering why do they need to do all those "authentication dance" instead of just creating a signature in order to validate each requests.